# Give page number in UIPageViewController content view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

My Content View has a top bar which showing Page 1 of 50 . How can i update this string when PageViewController moves left and right.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController DocumentPath]];

    NSLog(@"CURRENT PAGE IN CONTENTVIEW====%d",currentIndex-1);




}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController DocumentPath]];
NSLog(@"CURRENT PAGE IN CONTENTVIEW====%d",currentIndex+1);


}
```

The Above code always return wrong count, how can i solve this.

I need the particular page number in the content view. I mean in the viewdidload or something like that in the content view

Comment: Any answer to this question as i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it showing, if you just set the index in viewDidLoad of the viewController you are currently displaying by getting the index of the current viewController from the modelArray?

Comment: glad i could help. But maybe i should rephrase my answer a bit. :)

Comment: :The problem is when i flip the page to the middle and roll back,then also the page index is changing which is suppose to be the same since we cancelled page flipping..hope you are able to get my question

Comment: you can also set the correct pagenumber in `viewDidAppear`, instead of `viewDidLoad`. That way you will not have to set the pagenumber when you cancel the flipping.